# Enable Enterprise Features option missing in my Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, central-administration

I want to upgrade the existing Sharepoint installation to the Enterprise version, but there's "Enable Enterprise Features" option missing from my "Upgrade and Migration" portion of the Central Administration.

There are only three options under "Upgrade and Migration"
1. Check product and patch installation status
2. Review database status
3. Checek upgrade status

What am I missing? How can I upgrade this thing?

Comment: What are you upgrading from? Standard or Foundation? Also try and check upgrade status to see if an existing upgrade is in progress http://yourCA:5555/_admin/UpgradeStatus.aspx also check if your timer service (SPTimerV4) is running

Comment: From Foundation. I checked for upgrades in progress. There is none. Timer service is running as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upgrade directly from Foundation to Enterprise.

You need to use in-place or database attach upgrade approaches.

Follow the guide on TechNet [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262342).

Upgrade from standard CAL to enterprise:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261946

Comment: Thanks. Can I install Server version over this one without losing site collections, applications and other data on it (I can not understand whether I'm gonna lose data from that tutorial you sent me the link to)

Comment: Yeah in-place upgrade is the same as installing one on top of the other. I wouldnt do this on a production environment, but if it is only a test server this is definately an easy way to achieve what you want. My advice is to read the guidance i linked to from top to button (it adresses these issues) and then decide how to proceed

Comment: I did this, but now I can not open any of the old web applications. I get the message that An unexpected error has occurred.

Comment: check upgrade log or uls log in <SharePointRoot>/LOGS for relevant info. For more info on logs when upgrading SharePoint read my white paper http://andersrask.sharepointspace.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=25

Comment: Thanks for everything. Vote ups for answer and first comment, and I'm accepting this. That "unexpected error" problem was not related to my migration. As it turned out, that web application does not work on production either. All the others now work properly. Thanks once more.